# c++ transfer file line by line in reverse order

Tags: c++

I have this code that is supposed to transfer a file into another file in reverse order, line by line. However it does not work. Maybe I forgot to add something:

```
while(cnvFile.good()) {
    getline(cnvFile, cnvPerLine);

    reverseFile << cnvPerLine;
    reverseFile.seekp(0, ios::beg);
}
```

Comment: If my file has 3 lines 'a,b \n x, y \n p ,q \n' then you want 'p,q \n x,y \n a, b'? Or you also want elements of line reversed such as 'q, p \n y, x \n b, a '?

Comment: If you seek an output file to the beginning and then write to it, you'll overwrite whatever was written before.

Comment: @Dilawar Yes I want the it like 'p,q \n x,y \n a, b'..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you seek to the beginning and try to write, you're not *inserting* data, you're *overwriting* data. A simple (albeit probably far from optimal) solution would be something like:

```
std::string reversedContents
while (getline(inFile, line)) {
    // This actually *appends* to the beginning, not overwriting
    reversedContents = line + "\n" + reversedContents; // manually add line breaks back in
}

// now write reversedContents to a file...
```

Comment: @QuentinUK: Thanks for catching that!

Comment: @Cornstalks Hi sir, the code works great but the file has literally thousands of line and the code takes a good amount of time, is there something that we can do to shorted the time?

Comment: @jaa2013: with pure C++, there isn't a whole lot. You may be able to scan the file backwards, manually looking for newlines and then reading each line, but I'm not sure if that's more efficient. C++ gives you very limited power when it comes to things like this. Any "optimal" solutions will likely be platform/situation dependent.

Comment: Nothing in C++ forces you to use an o(N^2) algorithm to construct the output. Scanning the file backwards would be a lot more efficient (and wouldn't require keeping the file in memory if it were really big). Using a std::vector of std::strings and iterating through it backwards would be a lot more efficient. Or if you want to iterate forwards, a std::deque.

Comment: @rici just found something while googleling..you are right using vector is more efficient:
    stack<string> line;
    string temp;

    while(getline(myFile, temp))
        line.push(temp);

    while(!line.empty()) {
        reverseFile << line.top();
        line.pop();
    }
Thanks!